# Android GridView layout and optimization

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two questions, the first one is that I am creating a bunch of gridviews and the gridview items is just one imageview, when I put a 500 * 1000 image in the items(I only have four items) it lags like crazy but if I insert a lower res pic(100*200) it works fine. So can android not handle this?(I used view recycling too)

The second one is that I want my gridview items to be 125dp wide and have exactly 2dp vertical and horizontal spacing, if there is extra space I would want it to stretch the gridview items, I'm using this code in my xml for my grid view item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_icon"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ImageView>
```

and my gridview:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:columnWidth="125dp"     
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
    </GridView>
```

this is what i want:

[image: want]

and this is what im getting:[image: gridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview's layout code is ok, change `grid_item` layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the answer to my first question? can android not handle high res pictures?

Comment: @user3469274 : u r missing `scaleType` and `adjustViewBounds` attribute. But its better to use image with different resolution and place those images in different drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2" >
    </GridView>
```

Comment: just getting rid of the columnwidth attribute is still giving me the exact same result

Answer (score 0):

Just add attribute numColumns on your gridview in xml.

```
android:numColumns="2"
```

For more detail you have to read below link :-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: If it is being used by tablets i wouldnt want it to be 2 rows, so i prefer that the image width is the same and the numrows stays dynamic

Comment: then you have to make tablet layout

Comment: setting it to numrows=2 still doesnt help, maybe its because the item xml i should use matchparent as width and height?

Comment: numcolumns sorry typo

Comment: @user3469274 on imageview xml you wrote wrape content